# $digest() iterations reached. Aborting in AngularJs Application

Tags: angularjs

We built [our website](http://www.reviewmatters.com) in angularjs. From the last few days, we are getting below error in our website . You can easily reproduce this issue by going to http://www.reviewmatters.com/#!/directReview and then login using fb or twitter.

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=f.$$replace;if(!m||a!=f.absUrl())m++,\nc.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",f.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?f.$$parse(a):
```

Comment: I love reading minified javascript

Comment: please post relevant code in Fiddle/Plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally stopped using angular-cookies and wrote our own directory.I wonder if angularjs docs and bugs would ever be fixed.It took almost one week of our time .

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when two parts of your model update each other in a cycle. Angular sees that one value has changed so it starts another $digest iteration, which causes another change so another iteration occurs and so on. It's an infinite loop, but Angular catches it and stops after 10 (by default) iterations.

If you post the non-minified controller and the view that cause this we may be able to give a more concrete answer.